# Angular how to wait for data to be set in a controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using angular ui router, I have two simple states (each with 1 view + 1 controller):
- state1 is for a user to fill his profile
- state2 is to display the profile

So before going to state2, the user fills a form and I send / store the data using a Profile service in the state1 controller.

Anyway after this step, I use `$state.go('state2')`, however since the 'state2' controller has already been called (even before the user fills the profile form in 'state1' actually).

I'm now wondering how to set a $scope.profile property in the state2 controller whenever the data are submitted in state1

Maybe this is not the correct approach, but not sure which event to listen to get this specific $scope property to be set.

Comment: *however since the 'state2' controller has already been called*: no, it shouldn't have been called, since you're on state1. Post your code.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the data from one state to the next? Or are you loading the data for the second state from the server? If you "store" the data as you say in a service, you can retrieve it from there by injecting the same service to the second state, if that's what you want

Comment: @mxa055 how do you pass the data from one state to the next?
I use my service to retrieve the data , let' say `Profile.get();`

Comment: @JBNizet, it may be called before if there is a "parent" state, but anyway if it wasn't called, the 'state2' controller would be called only once, and the state may be reached multiple times, each time I need to retrieve the data.

Comment: We can't explain why your code behaves the way it does, and how to change it, without seeing a single line of it. Post your code.